# Record Screen with audio and get URL (ReplayKit)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, replaykit

I use `ReplayKit` to record screen with a microphone
How can I get `resultUrl` of video without saving the video in the gallery?
With this method, it works great without the microphone.

```
recorder.startCapture(handler: { (cmSampleBuffer, rpSampleType, error) in

})
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try setting `recorder.isMicrophoneEnabled ` to `true` ?

Comment: Yes
If I use
***recorder.startRecording *** microphone work good but I can not get URL of the video
if I use
***recorder.startCapture ***microphone does not work

Comment: did you try setting the value of `recorder.isMicrophoneEnabled` before calling, `recorder.startRecording` ?

Comment: I do not use recorder.startRecording
To got URL I need to use recorder.startCapture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving a screen recording with RPScreenRecorder start capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945152/saving-a-screen-recording-with-rpscreenrecorder-start-capture)